# Conflicting where clause in MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables, one with 'papers' (P), one with 'authors' (A) and one with 'authors__papers' (AP) which is a lookup table with a few other values as well. What I need is a single query that gives me one column with the author name where the 'is_contact_author' field in AP = 0, and another column with all the author names (concatenated) where AP.author_order > 0. These should be grouped by P.paper_id.

Each query by itself looks like:

```
SELECT CONCAT(A.first_name,' ',A.last_name) as contact FROM authors A
join authors__papers AP on AP.author_id = A.author_id 
WHERE  AP.is_contact_author = 0
```

And:

```
SELECT AP.paper_id, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(A.first_name,' ',A.last_name) ORDER BY AP.author_order SEPARATOR ', ') as authors FROM authors A
join authors__papers AP on AP.author_id = A.author_id 
WHERE  AP.author_order > 0
GROUP BY AP.paper_id
```

Each of those returns the expected separate result. I tried a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT CONCAT(A.first_name,' ',A.last_name) as contact FROM authors A
join authors__papers AP on AP.author_id = A.author_id 
WHERE  AP.is_contact_author = 1
) contact,

(
SELECT AP.paper_id, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(A.first_name,' ',A.last_name) ORDER BY AP.author_order SEPARATOR ', ') as authors FROM authors A
join authors__papers AP on AP.author_id = A.author_id 
WHERE  AP.author_order > 0
GROUP BY AP.paper_id
) author_info
```

But that hangs (or maybe is just REALLY slow). Any ideas how best to get this output from both queries in one result set? Every paper has one contact and at least one author. The author_order for contacts is always 0 and authors is 1 through X. The is_contact_author for contacts is always 1 and for authors is always 0 if that helps or matters.

Comment: You should use explicit `join` syntax (`select..from..join..on..`). You now have an implicit join with no conditions, this leads to a Cartesian product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it slow, there is not join condition so you are doing a Cartesian join.

Try this:

```
SELECT author_info.paper_id, author_info.authors, contact.contact FROM 
(
    SELECT AP.paper_id as paper_id2,CONCAT(A.first_name,' ',A.last_name) as contact FROM authors A
    join authors__papers AP on AP.author_id = A.author_id 
    WHERE  AP.is_contact_author = 1
) contact
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT AP.paper_id, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(A.first_name,' ',A.last_name) ORDER BY AP.author_order SEPARATOR ', ') as authors
    FROM authors A
    join authors__papers AP on AP.author_id = A.author_id 
    WHERE  AP.author_order > 0
    GROUP BY AP.paper_id
) author_info
ON(contact.paper_id = author_info.paper_id)
```

Try to use the proper syntax of joins, this will help you avoid this mistakes.

Comment: You have a superfluous `,`, after `contact`

Comment: Thanks @honeybadger

Comment: Is there a way to avoid having paper_id display twice?

Comment: If I remove AP.paper_id from the second SELECT, then the ON fails with unknown column author_info.paper_id. I'd like the paper_id only displayed once in the output.

Comment: DUH - never mind - figured it out - think I need more coffee... thanks!

Comment: I meant in the outer select:) No problem.